# C# how can add text to control

Tags: c#, user-interface, controls, label

I have a subclass from control and I want set text for that.
When I change parent to label this can be done but this class has sibling should be buttons.
Logically label and button can extends from Control therefore I extend my parent class from Control but now I can't write text on it.
Of course text property exists on it but i can't see my text.
Please help me ..
Thanks a lot

Comment: Button has property Content.  Try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the `Text` property to do what you need:

```
public override string Text
{
    get { return myButton.Text; }
    set { myButton.Text = value; }
}
```

(assuming you have a button in your custom control).

Answer (score 2):

Given your description (wanting a label for Text as well as a button)...

Instead of subclassing `Control`, it sounds like you should consider using a `UserControl`.  This allows you to make a "custom control" that's built by *composing* other controls, which means you can have a single `UserControl` containing a label (your Text) as well as your buttons, and treat it as a unified object.